# jQuery actions independent of id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working web page, but I would like to generalize the code. When one clicks a link with e.g. anchor #11 or #12, a div called #t11 or #t12 will open (or close) with this piece of script:

**Script**

```
$( "#11" ).click(function() {
$( "#t11" ).toggle();
});

$( "#12" ).click(function() {
$( "#t12" ).toggle();
});
```

**Stripped HTML**

```
<div class="a">
  <table>
    <tr><td><a id="11">Foo</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Find out more about Foo</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <table>
    <tr><td><a id="12">Bar</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Find out more about Bar</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="b" id="t11">
  <p>More info about Foo</p>
</div>
<div class="b" id="t12">
  <p>More info about Bar</p>
</div>
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
.b {
  display: none;
}
```

This is fine, however, with over 20 divs it's getting complicated and difficult to maintain. Is there a way to reduce the code, so every id in `<a>` will toggle its `<div>`? I've been struggling with `$this` but without the result I hoped for.

Comment: try this. `$( ".a a[id]" ).click(function() {
$('#'+$(this).attr("id")).toggleClass("b");
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a selector that will match all appropriate `<a>` elements, so that your click function will be applied to all of them. Then, you can get the `id` attribute from your `<a>` tag using `$(this).attr('id')`. You can then form a selector that matches the corresponding id of the content you want to toggle, then call the `.toggle()` method using that selector.

```js
$('.a table tr td a').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var selector = '#t' + id;
  $(selector).toggle();
});
```

```css
.b {
  display: none;
}
a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><a id="11">Foo</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Find out more about Foo</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><a id="12">Bar</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Find out more about Bar</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="b" id="t11">
  <p>More info about Foo</p>
</div>
<div class="b" id="t12">
  <p>More info about Bar</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

You may also consider adding a class to your actual `<a>` tags, as mentioned by @Lelio Faieta.

In the above example, if the structure of your html changes, the `$('.a table tr td a')` selector will break, and the click functionality will be lost.

If, however, you assign a class of, say `toggler` to each `<a>` tag, then you can just replace the `$('.a table tr td a')` selector with `$('.toggler')` and your click functionality will still work if you change the location of your `<a>` tags in your html.

```js
$('.toggler').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var selector = '#t' + id;
  $(selector).toggle();
});
```

```css
.b {
  display: none;
}
a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><a id="11" class="toggler">Foo</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Find out more about Foo</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><a id="12" class="toggler">Bar</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Find out more about Bar</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="b" id="t11">
  <p>More info about Foo</p>
</div>
<div class="b" id="t12">
  <p>More info about Bar</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, this solves everything, thanks for the very quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes to group elements in jquery.
A class is referenced like id but with a dot instead of a dash:

```
$('.someClass')
```

where you used to write

```
$('#anID')
```

Many objects can share the same class so you can both use classes to target an animation to multiple objects at the same time or to use different element on the DOM to fire an animation

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is by adding a common class to all a tag and performing event with that class.

```
<a class="atag" id="11">
<a class="atag" id="12">


$(".atag").click(function() {
   var id=$(this).attr("id");
   $(body).find("#"+id).toggle();
});
```